# Не понятно что такое IEnumerable<int[]>, yield и foreach

Tags: c#, массивы, математика, комбинаторика

Я нашел код программы которая перебирает сочетания из n по k. Но не могу разобраться  в некоторых моментах. В частности мне не понятно что такое IEnumerable<int[]>, yield и foreach. Помогите переделать код так, что бы был использован массив int и цикл for.

P.S. Разъяснить логику работы данной функции тоже не помешало бы)

```
public class Program
{
  public static IEnumerable<int[]> FindCombosRec(int[] buffer, int done, int begin, int end)
  {
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++)
    {
      buffer[done] = i;
 
      if (done == buffer.Length - 1)
        yield return buffer;
      else
        foreach (int[] child in FindCombosRec(buffer, done+1, i+1, end))
          yield return child;
    }
  }
 
  public static IEnumerable<int[]> FindCombinations(int m, int n)
  {
    return FindCombosRec(new int[m], 0, 0, n);
  }
 
  static void Main()
  {
    foreach (int[] c in FindCombinations(3, 5))
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
      {
        Console.Write(c[i] + " ");
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В частности мне не понятно что такое IEnumerable<int[]>, yield и foreach. Помогите переделать код так, что бы был использован массив int и цикл for

вам стоит не программу перепеписывать в допотопноим стиле с массивами и циклами for, а потратить пару часов на то, чтобы изучить то, что вам непонятно. Поверьте, это существенно более удобные средства, чем то, что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Ну я так и сделал.. Не знаю теперь как вопрос удалить.